# app segues before my data is populated causing the table view no to populate

Tags: ios, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have an app that queries iTunes. When the data returns I want to segue from the search screen to a tableview that displays the songs.

My problem: I'm getting the data back but my segue is happening before the data is back so the numberOfRowsInSection count is still 0 and my app just stops. I don't understand why the conditional doesn't execute before my performselector method.

Here's my code:

```
    - (IBAction)searchForTrack:(id)sender {
NSString *trackName = [[NSString alloc]init];
tracks = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
trackName = _searchText.text;
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSString *appURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=%@",trackName];
//NSLog(appURL);
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:appURL] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSMutableDictionary *jsonDict= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    //NSLog(@"%@", jsonDict); 
    if (jsonDict)
    {
        for (id trackDict in [jsonDict objectForKey:@"results"]){
            Track *track = [[Track alloc] initWithJSONDictionary:trackDict];
            NSString *trackName = [trackDict objectForKey:@"trackName"];
            NSString *artistName = [trackDict objectForKey:@"artistName"];
            NSString *trackPrice = [trackDict objectForKey:@"trackPrice"];
            NSString *releaseDate = [trackDict objectForKey:@"releaseDate"];
            NSString *primaryGenreName = [trackDict objectForKey:@"primaryGenreName"];
            [tracks addObject:track];
    }
}
else
    {
        NSLog(@"No Darn Tracks Were Found or Something else is screwed up");
    }
}];
[dataTask resume];
[self performSelector:@selector(switchToTableview)];
}
```

Comment: Are you downloading that JSON via an asynchronous method? If so, that's your problem.

Comment: sorry, just posted the rest of the method. maybe this will help

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the full code, but the

```
}];
```

give's the clue that the conditional code is being executed in a block.

Your code is not executing in a one-line-at-a-time manner due to the block which is probably the cause of the problem, but you need to post all the code to confirm and to suggest the best solution (which will be remove the block, or add a completion part to the block).

Comment: sorry, just posted the rest of the method.

Comment: Try putting the call to switchToTableview inside the block completion handler not outside it.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: Move this line [self performSelector:@selector(switchToTableview)]; to  after the for loop. (I am presuming it is switchToTableView which is invoking your segue.)

Comment: your presumption is correct. I moved the  [self performSelector:@selector(switchToTableview)]; to after the for loop. I have the same issue. For some strange reason the for loop doesn't execute first so the variable that i use to populate the table is empty when it segues

Comment: Doesn't execute first before what? The segue? Is the seque being invoked elsewhere

Comment: I expect my loop to complete and then segue. When I debug the loop doesn't happen until after the segue no matter where I put [self performSelector:@selector(switchToTableview)];

Comment: And what if there is no perform selector at all?

Comment: if there's no perform selector, the if condition works just fine but then I have to find another alternative to segue.